# MySQL LOCK table in ORACLE

Tags: mysql, oracle, locking

I'm trying to lock some tables in Oracle. My MySQL query looks like this:

```
LOCK TABLES mytable WRITE;
```

I tried using this query in Oracle:

```
LOCK TABLE mytable IN SHARE MODE;
```

I get "LOCK succeeded" message but I'm still able to SELECT from this table in another session.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Locks are only to prevent any updates/inserts. If you want to restrict SELECT, you might try revoking the privilege.

Comment: By revoking the SELECT privilege my session wouldn't be able to SELECT any data as well, am I correct?

Comment: Yes. You may have to a use a different id for `READ/WRITE` and `READ ONLY`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle uses multi-version read consistency.  That means, among other things, that readers never block writers and writers never block readers.  As a result, there is no lock that you can take out that would prevent a user (with appropriate privileges, of course) from querying the table.  In the vast, vast majority of cases, it wouldn't make sense to prevent readers from reading the data; even if you're deleting all the data and re-inserting it in a different session, as long as you're doing that in a single transaction, the readers and writers would never block each other.  Explicitly locking a table in Oracle, similarly, would be exceedingly unusual-- I haven't personally come across a situation in my Oracle career where explicitly locking a table made sense.

If you really need to prevent readers from reading data, you'd need to implement your own serialization mechanism.  You could, for example use the `dbms_lock` to acquire a custom lock before your writer starts and then code the reader processes to check that lock before executing a `SELECT` statement.  Or you could have a table of running processes that you maintain, write to as part of the load process, and code the reader processes to check that table before doing any reads.  Like I said above, though, it would be most unusual for it to make sense to add this sort of complexity to your system.

Answer (score 0):

Try [REVOKE/GRANT](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/grant_revoke.php) Privileges:

```
REVOKE SELECT ON mytable FROM public;
```

On the side note, you can define users as well if you want the privileges be exclusive to a group.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle was intended to be used different way. Generally when you need to lock a table in Oracle "there is something wrong with your design", because your application won't scale. Moreover `LOCK TABLE` statement has some rare limitations. For example it is not propagated onto logical standby.

Comment: I use table locks in MySQL to avoid users selecting the same data. For example, an application to call the next person in queue. In MySQL, when there are many users "calling" at the same time, it might happen that two users get the same next number. I avoid that using table read locks. This can't happen in Oracle?

Comment: For similar purposes Oracle has it's own queening/messaging system called "Advanced queuing" (AQ). Or are you using this type of locking to "pick the next available resource"? Like table contains a list ticket numbers and each of them can be sold only once?